# What's the name of an area split by Bar Line (s) called?

Tags: notation, terminology

What is the unit name of an area split by Bar Line(s) called ?

(See the red-circled area in below picture)

[image: Amazing Grace]

The translation from my native language to English results in **Time Signature** .

I feel that it's quite not right, but I don't know, maybe that just me.

This is the simple 1-sentence version of the question :

> **Fill in the blank** : The area which is red-circled in above picture is called as 1 (one) ______________

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The metrical unit you are referring to is called **bar** or **measure**.

> The area which is red-circled in above picture is called as 1 (one) **Bar** or **Measure**

The *bar lines* break your notes into **bars** and are [used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_%28music%29) to provide regular reference points to pinpoint locations within a piece of music.

Comment: Of possible note for a non-native English speaker is that American convention is to call it a 'measure', while British convention is to call it a 'bar'. We tend to understand each other's terminology though.

Comment: @MatthewWalton "bar" and "measure" are both commonly used in the United States. "Bar" is by no means a primarily British term.

Comment: @phoog - conversly, U.K. tend not to use 'measure'. French do, but with a French accent, of course - 'mayzuoor'! Can't find any word resembling that in modern German.

Comment: @phoog ah nice, I assumed since we just never say "measure" here that Americans never say "bar".

Comment: @MatthewWalton A classic example is *Boogie-Woogie Bugle Boy,* which includes the line "he blows it eight to the bar in boogie rhythm."  I wonder when "measure" fell out of use in the UK.  Do you know?  (The OED's last citation is from 1878, the Grove dictionary: "the word bar is also commonly, though incorrectly, applied to the portion contained between any two such vertical lines [bars], such portion being termed a 'measure'.")

Comment: @phoog I have no idea - it's been "bar" here for as long as I can remember, learning music as a child it was all about "bars" and my Mum, who did a lot of music when she was at school in the 60s, also just uses "bar". So I'm guessing it's a pre-war change.

Comment: @MatthewWalton that makes sense.  Maybe I'll ask over at [English.SE].  I was trying to find one word or the other in Vaughan Williams's writings, but don't have good enough access to them.

Comment: I have seen a beginner's piano book in which the bar lines were called bars, and the spaces between were called measures.

Answer (score 3):

It's called one bar.That's why they're bar lines, they separate bars. The time signature at the beginning of a piece tells how many beats of which sort each bar will contain. As in this tune - 3/4 tells 3 of one beat note length. Sometimes called quarter beats - the Americans think a 'full' bar would have one long beat in it (a semibreve), so they call this 'three-quarter time' The usual bottom notes are crotchets (one beat  or quarter) notes, and the top number tells how many fit into each bar. Where the first, and then subsequent, barlines go is usually defined by the louder or more stressed notes, or in this case, word/syllable. As in aMAzing GRACE, how SWEET the SOUND.